# Richfaces Calendar Today Date

Tags: calendar, richfaces

I am trying to change the "today" date in richfaces calendar module. I could not find anything in the CalendarDataModel provided by richfaces thus im trying to find the answer here. I am not talking about the selected date.

Use Case:

- I am opening the calendar by clicking on the input and instead of current day and the preselected current month I want to get displayed November the 14th.

Wider explanation:

- I have two different inputs which depend on each other. The date selected in the first input should be the "today" date in the second input.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Following code sets date from first calendar to second and rerender second calendar component. Code not sets today date for second calendar. System date is used as today date and it is the same date for first and second calendars. Code:

```
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel for="from" value="From" />
        <rich:calendar id="from" value="#{t1Calendar.from}"
            datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy" enableManualInput="true">
            <a4j:ajax event="change" render="to"/>
        </rich:calendar>

        <h:outputLabel for="to" value="To" />
        <rich:calendar id="to" value="#{t1Calendar.to}"
            datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy" enableManualInput="true" popup="true"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
public class T1Calendar {
    private Date from = new Date();
    private Date to;

    public Date getFrom() { return from; }
    public void setFrom(Date from) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = from;
    }
    public Date getTo() { return to; }
    public void setTo(Date to) { this.to = to; }

}
```